# Using PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager in EJB container

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

- We want to use HttpClient inside EJB container of Glassfish 3.1 Open
  source edition.
- In [HttpClient documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) we see the following
  line regarding BasicHttpClientConnectionManager: "This connection
  manager implementation should be used inside an EJB container".
- There is no such line in PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager documentation.
- Can we use PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager in EJB container?
- If not - can you explain why?

Answer (score 2):

You can but explicit thread management when running inside an EJB container is prohibited by the EJB 3.1 spec, which effectively renders PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager's pooling capabilities almost useless.

Comment: Are you sure of your answer?  I don't think the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager itself does any internal thread creation or management-- and pooling has other uses besides using it for doing concurrent http calls.

Comment: I have the same question as the OP-- it seems that the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager is a better fit for my use.   I have it in a Singleton that is called by multiple threads.  Each of those threads get a connection from the pool, use it, and then return it.  I want to do this because the http calls are always to the same server, and that server requires NTLM authentication, and the http calls are always made using the same user credentials.

Comment: I am fairly sure. What would other uses besides using it for doing concurrent http calls be?

Comment: In an EJB container, there are multiple container managed threads that are running concurrently.  If those each need access to an expensive authenticated http connection to the same target webserver, then they can share a single HttpClient.  Each of those threads can pull a connection from that same HttpClient (which is using the  PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager).  Those threads would get a CloseableHttpRequest from httpClient.execute() and close that when done with them.  So the concurrency is there, it's just using threads already created by the container.

Comment: It would work absolutely the _same_ way with the single connection. However instead of a pool of connections that the container has no control over one would end up with a pool of HttpClient instances nicely managed by the container. But suit yourself.

Comment: You've piqued my interest.  Is it easy to create a pool of HttpClient instances?  Do EJB Containers have a good solution for doing that?  If you say yes, I would create new a new question for that.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is, if you wrap it into stateless session bean